# MySQL Union Not Working As Expected

Tags: mysql, union

I have tables:

Streams:

```
+----+-------------------+------------+
| id | channel           | bouquet    |
+----+-------------------+------------+
|  1 | USA_CH 1          | ["1","28"] |
|  2 | USA_CH 2          | ["1","28"] |
| 11 | USA_CH 3          | ["1"]      |
| 12 | USA_CH 4          | ["28"]     |
+----+-------------------+------------+
```

Channels:

```
+----+--------------------------+---------+----------+
| id | sort                     | bouquet | reseller |
+----+--------------------------+---------+----------+
|  1 | ["m1","1","2","m2","11"] | ["1"]   |        0 |
| 27 | ["1","2"]                | ["28"]  |        0 |
| 39 | []                       | ["33"]  |        0 |
+----+--------------------------+---------+----------+
```

Markers:

```
+----+--------+-------+---------+----------+
| id | marker | title | bouquet | reseller |
+----+--------+-------+---------+----------+
|  1 | m1     | MEGA  |       1 |        1 |
+----+--------+-------+---------+----------+
|  2 | m2     | XTRA  |       1 |        1 |
+----+--------+-------+---------+----------+
```

And need to get channels order with marker from channels table sort field:

```
["m1","1","2","m2","11"]
```

So i need to get output like this:

```
+----+-------------------+
| id | channel           |
+----+-------------------+
|  1 | MEGA              |
|  1 | USA_CH 1          |
|  2 | USA_CH 2          |
|  2 | XTRA              |
| 11 | USA_CH 3          |
+----+-------------------+
```

I try using union SQL:

```
SELECT s.id, s.channel, m.title FROM streams s, markers m, channels c WHERE JSON_SEARCH(s.bouquet, 'one', '1') IS NOT NULL AND 
JSON_SEARCH(c.bouquet, 'one', '1') IS NOT NULL AND JSON_SEARCH(c.sort, 'one', s.id) IS NOT NULL
UNION 
SELECT s.id, s.channel, m.title FROM streams s, markers m, channels c WHERE JSON_SEARCH(c.sort, 'one', m.marker) IS NOT NULL AND
JSON_SEARCH(s.bouquet, 'one', '1') IS NOT NULL;
```

And i get this:

```
 +----+----------+-------+
  | id | channel  | title |
  +----+----------+-------+
  |  1 | USA_CH 1 | MEGA  |
  |  2 | USA_CH 2 | MEGA  |
  | 11 | USA_CH 3 | XTRA  |
  +----+----------+-------+
```

And i need to get this:

```
+----+-------------------+
| id | channel           |
+----+-------------------+
|  1 | MEGA              |
|  1 | USA_CH 1          |
|  2 | USA_CH 2          |
|  2 | XTRA              |
| 11 | USA_CH 3          |
+----+-------------------+
```

What i have done wrong? I read on mysql manual that UNION is for merging two tables values into one...so i was thinking that i will get this result that i need but as you see in my example code i get always from each table each row value..and needs to be value after value corresponding to channels.sort json value...i im building channel ediotor in html5 so i need to get ordering of channels and reading channels name and markers as defined in channels.sort.

Comment: Why not normalise your schema?

Comment: if you don't want to select `title` column then why did you include it in `select` statement&

Comment: union just append the records from the second table to the first one. So the error comes from the two queries and not from the union

Comment: Thanks for comments...yes you are right i could exclude markers.title fro m query and it is not needed but i could not get query that gives me output that i need..could be please more specific what mysql command i need to use? I see now that UNION is not good for what i need

Comment: Again, there is nothing wrong with the union itself. The individual queries are at fault. You should test them individually and highlight the issues with them. Pls note that you do not seem to provide join criteria for all of the tables in your queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it! Yupiiiii.... :)

```
SELECT id, sort, channel FROM
(
SELECT s.id, c.sort, s.channel FROM streams s, channels c
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(s.bouquet, 'one', '1') IS NOT NULL AND
JSON_SEARCH(c.bouquet, 'one', '1') IS NOT NULL AND JSON_SEARCH(c.sort, 'one', s.id) IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT m.marker, c.sort, m.channel FROM markers m, channels c, streams s
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(m.bouquet, 'one', '1') IS NOT NULL AND
JSON_SEARCH(c.bouquet, 'one', '1') IS NOT NULL AND JSON_SEARCH(c.sort, 'one', m.marker) IS NOT NULL
) A
ORDER BY LOCATE(id, CONCAT("'", sort, "'"));
```

And i got nice output:

```
+----+--------------------------+----------+
| id | sort                     | channel  |
+----+--------------------------+----------+
| m1 | ["m1","1","2","m2","11"] | MEGA     |
| 1  | ["m1","1","2","m2","11"] | USA_CH 1 |
| 2  | ["m1","1","2","m2","11"] | USA_CH 2 |
| m2 | ["m1","1","2","m2","11"] | XTRA     |
| 11 | ["m1","1","2","m2","11"] | USA_CH 3 |
+----+--------------------------+----------+
```

Thanks guys for commenting above example that my single query in UNION is wrong..using detail try and error i got it finally..so if someone needs code here is it